# Grid of buttons over image with inset?

Tags: button

I'm in-setting a grid of buttons over an image, and I think it's probably a very simple thing that I'm missing.  In the example below `Scaled` doesn't work to stretch the `Button`'s properly:

```
Graphics[{Inset[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], Scaled[{0, 1}], 
   Scaled[{0, 1}], Scaled[1]],
  Inset[Button["test", Print[1], Background -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0, 0.3],
     ImageSize -> Automatic], Scaled[{0, 1}], Scaled[{0, 1}], 
   Scaled[{1, 1/2}]],
  Inset[Button["test", Print[1], Background -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0.3], 
    ImageSize -> Automatic], Scaled[{0, 1/2}], Scaled[{0, 1/2}], 
   Scaled[{1, 1/2}]]
  }, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

It should look like this:

[image]

The above I made with this:

```
Overlay[{ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], 
  TextGrid[{{Button["test", Print[1], 
      Background -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0, 0.3], 
      ImageSize -> {512, 256}]}, {Button["test", Print[2], 
      Background -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0, 0.3], 
      ImageSize -> {512, 256}]}}, Spacings -> {0, 0}]}]
```

Which would be a solution except that:

- I don't want to give explicit `ImageSize`s
- `Overlay` kills the buttons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the second and third arguments of `Overlay`:

```
image = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]; 
Overlay[{image,  
  TextGrid[{{Button["test", Print[1], Background -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0, 0.3], 
      ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[image]/{1, 2}]},
    {Button["test",  Print[2], Background -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0, 0.3], 
      ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[image]/{1, 2}]}}, 
   Spacings -> {0, 0}]}, All, 2]
```

Alternatively, use `ImageSize -> {Scaled[1], Scaled[1/2]}` with `Button` and use `Scaled[1]` as the size argument in `Inset`:

```
Graphics[{Inset[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], Scaled[{0, 1}], 
   Scaled[{0, 1}], Scaled[1]], 
 Inset[Button["test", Print[1], Background -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0, 0.3], 
    ImageSize -> {Scaled[1], Scaled[1/2]}], 
  Scaled[{0, 1}], Scaled[{0, 1}], Scaled[1]], 
 Inset[Button["test", Print[2], Background -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0, 0.3],
     ImageSize -> {Scaled[1], Scaled[1/2]}], 
  Scaled[{0, 1/2}], Scaled[{0, 1}], Scaled[1]]},
PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```